# Works, but Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined when i type it in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I made a Tic Tac Toe game in js and i have a couple of arrays.

-One for the html td elements (grid)
-One to see if they have been clicked on before (boolGrid)
-And one to check the end condition with colors (colorgrid)

I defined all of these in global scope with the var keyword and their contents, now the game does work but when i type their name in the console it gives me the Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined. I'm wondering what's up with that since i am trying to make an OXO game next.

Here are the links to the code,
TicTacToe: https://jsfiddle.net/NeuroTypicalCure/0k73umd1/3/
My progress on OXO: https://jsfiddle.net/NeuroTypicalCure/vdz5q97v/ (clearly unfinished)

```
    var grid = [
    document.getElementById("a").children[0],
    document.getElementById("a").children[1],
    document.getElementById("a").children[2],
    document.getElementById("b").children[0],
    document.getElementById("b").children[1],
    document.getElementById("b").children[2],
    document.getElementById("c").children[0],
    document.getElementById("c").children[1],
    document.getElementById("c").children[2],
];
var boolGrid = [
    false,false,false,
    false,false,false,
    false,false,false
];
var colorGrid = [
    "grey","grey","grey",
    "grey","grey","grey",
    "grey","grey","grey"
];
var resetButton = document.getElementById("rb");

var color = "green";
var clicks = 0;

function allTiles(color){
    for(var i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
        grid[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        boolGrid[i] = true;
    }
}
function init(){
    for(var i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
        grid[i].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        boolGrid[i] = false;
        colorGrid[i] = "grey";
    }
}
function listen(arr,num){
    arr[num].addEventListener("click",function(){
            if(clicks == 0 || clicks%2 == 0){
                color = "green";
            }else{
                color = "red";
            }
            if(boolGrid[num] === false){
                arr[num].style.backgroundColor = color;
                boolGrid[num] = true;
                colorGrid[num] = color;
                clicks++;
                checkEnd("green");
                checkEnd("red");
            }
        });
}
function addEventListeners(){
    for(var i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
        listen(grid,i);
    }
}
function checkEnd(color){
    // ----------------- horizontal --------------
    if(colorGrid[0] === color && colorGrid[1] == color && colorGrid[2] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    if(colorGrid[3] === color && colorGrid[4] == color && colorGrid[5] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    if(colorGrid[6] === color && colorGrid[7] == color && colorGrid[8] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    //------------ vertical --------------
    if(colorGrid[0] === color && colorGrid[3] == color && colorGrid[6] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    if(colorGrid[1] === color && colorGrid[4] == color && colorGrid[7] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    if(colorGrid[2] === color && colorGrid[5] == color && colorGrid[8] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    // ------------------ diagonal -------------------
    if(colorGrid[0] === color && colorGrid[4] == color && colorGrid[8] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
    if(colorGrid[2] === color && colorGrid[4] == color && colorGrid[6] === color){
        console.log(color+"Wins!");
        allTiles(color);
    }
}
init();
addEventListeners();
resetButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    init();
})
```

Feel free to leave me any tips or corrections, thx in advance :)

Best of luck on your projects,
-T

Comment: you need to know how the console works - using the console on jsfiddle is not the way to debug a problem

Comment: "This is an obligatory code segment, but js fiddle is more easy, for me at least." — Try making it easy for the people you want to answer your question. Put your code here.

Comment: I added the code for you Quentin :)

Comment: Jaromanda X, could you tell me how the console works then?
And how i should debug a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you specified, the game works fine, what fails is when you try to access a variable using the console (in JSFiddle?) that fails. That happens for two reasons:

1. The context of the console.
2. The scope of the variables.

Simplifying a bit: the context of the console is the document that will be affected by the console actions. By default in Chrome, the context is the top frame, but it can be changed using a dropdown at the top left corner:

[image]

In your case, you are using JSFiddle, and JSFiddle uses an `iframe` to show the results. If the scope of the console is the "<top frame>", then you will not be able to access the variables from the result window. You need to change the dropdown to the "result (fiddle.jshell.net/)" value.

But, even if you do that, you will still get the error. Why is that? because of the second reason: the scope of the variable. Again simplifying a bit, a variable scope is the part of the program that can see/access the variable. It can be the whole application (global variable) or just a part of it (local variable).

In your case, you are using the `var` keyword inside a function (even if you don't think that you are using it inside a function, you actually are as you selected "On load" for the JavaScript execution and that will wrap your code inside an anonymous function executed on window load), and that makes all the variables local to that function.

When you try to print the variables from the console, they cannot be accessed because their scope was that particular function and they don't exist outside of it. To solve this:

- Make the variables global by removing the `var` keyword. This option is not recommended as it could have unexpected results (the variable could be accessed by any function and debugging/maintenance could become a nightmare); Or
- Instead of using the "onLoad" option for executing the JavaScript, use the "No wrap - in <body>". That way your code will not be wrapped in `window.onload=function(){ }`, but go directly in a `<script>` at the bottom of the body.

Although technically, what you are doing is making the variables global (because even with `var`, they are outside of all functions so they'd accessible by anyone).

**tl;dr;** - to solve the issue:

1. Change the context of the console to the iframe.
2. Change the scope of the variables so they can be accessed by the console.

Comment: Your answer is amazing and just what i was looking for.
Thanks a lot!